# How to hide Safari Mobile browser bottom button bar in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, html, css, mobile-safari

**Following is head section:**

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

    <meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/custom_icon.png"/>
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="/startup.png">

    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

    <script>
      window.top.scrollTo(0, 1);
      alert('ok');
      google.load("jquery", "1.4.1");
      google.load("jqueryui", "1.8.0");
    </script>

</head>
```

### using iOS 4.2.1

Above is not working for me. Browser Address bar and bottom toolbar are still there. I have tried some tutorials but I am unable to change anything. Any idea?

Comment: You cannot hide the toolbar in Mobile Safari. Simple as that. An iOS web app is something that users need to add to their home screens.

Comment: **add to their home screens**.. Can you please describe this a little more ??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot programmatically hide the toolbar in Mobile Safari.

Your users need to add your web app to their home screens in order for the bars to be hidden when they next launch your app by tapping its icon. This is done by tapping the middle button in the toolbar, then choosing **Add to Home Screen**. You may need to display a message informing your users to do this.

Comment: even when my web app is fired from the home screen the bottom toolbar remains (the top one is hidden). Why does the bottom remain? I am using JQuery Mobile.

Comment: Refer to the code in the question. Pay attention to the meta tags.

Comment: Excellent advice - if your users are going to be using your site often, have them add as a webapp - works like a charm!

Comment: This only works for the page that you add to your homescreen though right? If you click a link and move to some other page on the same site the top and bottom bars appear again.

Comment: @TV's Frank: Yes, which is why web apps need to handle navigation differently.

Answer (score 19):

For iOS 7.1, you can set this in your header to minimize the UI:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimal-ui">
```

It was introduced in iOS 7.1 beta 2.  This site was instrumental in helping me understand how minimal-ui works: http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/ios-7-1-safari-minimal-ui-bugs

Comment: This is no longer supported with IOS 8 onward.