# Kendo UI - Hide button bar in safari browser

Tags: safari, kendo-ui

Can we hide button bar in safari browser using Kendo UI api? Found the api to hide the address bar but not able to find the api for hiding button bar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hide Safari Mobile browser bottom button bar in iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191240/how-to-hide-safari-mobile-browser-bottom-button-bar-in-iphone)

Comment: This is a duplicate, yes, and not possible. Additionally to the provided answers, there is now fullscreen support in iOS6 when in landscape orientation and Kendo UI Mobile does support it.