# Hack to hide Safari's lower navigation bar for mobile app

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile, safari, navigation

I spent all morning searching, but haven't found anything yet. Really need your help for a javascript or creative hack to hide Safari's lower (navigation) bar when viewing our mobile app on iPhone. Our mobile site was built in jQuery Mobile. We have no need for the navigation bar since we have our own back button, and we're trying to reclaim that extra real estate. Most importantly, we want the site to feel more like a native app without having to go thru all the packaging/IOS steps, posting in the app stores etc, just to get the safari nav bar removed. We were able to hide the URL address bar (there's plenty of great solutions there). I do already know the meta tag / etc for adding to iphone home screen to remove the safari bars. That only helps a really small portion of the customers, maybe 1%. So basically looking for a creative hack to hide Safari's lower (navigation) bar when viewing our mobile app on iPhone. Thanks for your time and your help.

Answer (score 0):

As said by `BoltClock♦` in this post: [How to hide Safari Mobile browser bottom button bar in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191240/how-to-hide-safari-mobile-browser-bottom-button-bar-in-iphone)

```
You cannot programmatically hide the toolbar in Mobile Safari.

Your users need to add your web app to their home screens in order for the bars to be hidden when they next launch your app by tapping its icon. This is done by tapping the middle button in the toolbar, then choosing Add to Home Screen. You may need to display a message informing your users to do this.
```

Comment: Right. I just said I'm not looking for that solution. That only helps a tiny % of people (generally the developer of a site who needs to keep referencing his live site thru something faster than a bookmark). The average user isn't going to think your site is so tremendously important that they're going to create space on their phone's home screen just for you). I'm not looking for an obvious or easy answer. The easiest answer is always "it cannot be done". Anyone can write that. That contributes nothing.

Comment: I think showing/hiding the toolbar is regulated on the iPhone/iPad, thus it cannot be accessible using some hack (Unless you hack the device itself by jailbreaking, etc.) This is not a matter of simply saying you can't, because you actually can't.

Comment: Yep, that may also be true. Thanks for writing in. Well, I'd be willing to give a generous reward to someone who can find a non-jailbreak-related solution (that we would code into the jQuery Mobile backend or source for the mobile site) and that we can verify. Thanks.