# Safari iOS back button preventDefault

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, mobile-safari

I have an issue with Safari when it comes to User Experience.

You have a mobile version of a website, you have a section, you click on it, a panel opens up with info. You have an X button so you can click it, but you also have a "back button" at the bottom of the page (Safari).

[image]

Our tests concluded that users tend to click the back button (since it's at the bottom of the screen), thinking that they would close the panel they are in, and return to the home page.

However, that back button gets them out of the page itself. I though about adding a hash #panel1, #panel2 when they open a section, and when they click back I would just delete the hash, but it doesn't work.

What is there to be done?

Comment: Can you please write it in english? I'm developing for a danish company, although I don't speak it yet

Comment: Since this is a native safari functionality, this can't be disabled. However, [seems that you can hide the bottom navigation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23122357/1763929).