# iPhone safari bottom bar

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, safari

I'm having a problem with iPhone safari bottom bar (the one with back and forward buttons, new tab button and other stuff). In my app, I have an absolute positioned button at the bottom of the screen which is 100% width and almost the same height as the safari bottom bar and **my button is that way behind the safari bar** and not visible. Is there any way to know if the safari bottom bar is there so that I know when to move my content or even better is there a way to remove it completely?

I tried this:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

And also the minimal-ui tag but it didn't work.

Comment: maybe this could help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191240/how-to-hide-safari-mobile-browser-bottom-button-bar-in-iphone

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I don't think there is a way to completely remove the bar.

Although I thought about listening the screen getting resized (because that's what's happening). So I just had a JS/jQuery function that (in my case) changed the min-height of a block to screen height.

```
$(window).resize(...); // For example
```

Also adding transition in css would make things look much better (although transitions in mobile safari are also working weirdly if I recall everything correctly)

Hope this helps somehow.

If you find a smarter way to do this, please, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

may be this works

```css
#root {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.pane {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.bar {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="#root">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="pane"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "*maybe?*". Post only *answers* as answers. If you're unsure, kindly wait till you have earned enough reputation points to **comment**.